# TPH for Reporting

Tags: entity-framework

We are using EF Core with TPH (table-per-hierarchy) with VS 2017 and SQL Server 2016.

Just wanted to solicit some advice in terms of what people are doing to report off a TPH database.  Normally, databases are denormalized for reporting purposes.  Should a TPH database be handled any differently?  Any special precautions to take?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TPH is the least normalized of the inheritance mapping strategies, as the whole inheritance hierarchy shares a single table.  It's also, therefore, the simplest for reporting.

You still may want to create views for reporting, both to simplify the report writing, and to de-couple the reports from the underlying table design.

Comment: I agree that TPH is much better for reporting than TPT is. In fact, it is altogether more performant, especially when you host on Azure SQL, where you pay for throughput. Further denormalization might still be desired, depending on your use case. However the process of denormalization for reporting is pretty much the same as with TPT, all-be-it simpler.